# cannot build libpqxx with latest c++ language standard

Tags: c++, postgresql, build, libpqxx

I needed to work with postgreSQL and C++ so the most common library out there for this is libpqxx. I cloned the repo and switched to latest branch available right now (branch 7.6) and then used CMake to build the visual studio solution file.

But I cannot build this with latest preview features language standard OR even C++20 language standard. After searching for a bit I discovered that the error related to the header file ciso646 has something to do with C++20 removing != operator. This is very annoying as now I cannot make my project's language standard as C++20 either because of this. Here is a screenshot of the build errors:
[image]

So I reduced the language standard to C++17 and then tried to build and it still gave me a LOT of warnings before getting built successfully. The warnings were something of the sort:

```
warning C5051: attribute 'likely' requires at least '/std:c++20'; ignored
```

Even though now it is built and I got my include and lib files I am not sure if these warnings can cause any problems for me in the future.
Anyhow my question is can something be done to be able to build this library using c++20 or am I stuck working with c++17 because of this?